# What are the little numbers for next to the job postings?

Tags: support, jobs

http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/

What are the numbers for inside the tiny cue balls next to some listings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Their score on the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html).